# How do I change my clickable square image into a circular image on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

How do I change my clickable square image into a circular image on Flutter?

```
body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: TextButton(
                    child: Image.asset(
                      'assets/mia.png',
                      height: 250,
                      width: 250,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Nkunga()),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make the image circular, you may use CliRRect with a borderRadius like this:

```
ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(80.0),
              child: Image.asset(
                'assets/mia.png',
                height: 250,
                width: 250,
              ),
            ),
```